# Rasterize multiple fields of a shapefile at once

Tags: python, gis, qgis, rasterize

I have to rasterize each 62 columns of 30 big shapefiles (>8million cells) resulting in 1860 rasters.

I'm able to do this in R with smaller shapes (~ 8000 features) quite easily and fast. However, when just trying to load this big shape in R, it took me 2 hours, 16G RAM and 47% of my 64G swap. When calling the rasterize function, it can't run because of the memory.
However I figured out that QGIS can do it pretty fast, but for each column at once, which would took me a life to run that. 
I tried to use the Python console in QGIS with a loop to iterate over the columns, but I had no success.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import processing
import sys

layer = "path/to/my.shp"
iface.addVectorLayer(layer, "pam", "ogr")

attrs = layer.attributes()

extent = layer.extent()
xmin = extent.xMinimum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()

for n in attrs:
    processing.runalg("gdalogr:rasterize",
                   {"INPUT":layer,
                   "FIELD":n,
                   "DIMENSIONS":0,
                   "WIDTH":0.008333,
                   "HEIGHT":0.008333,
                   "RAST_EXT":"%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
                   "TFW":1,
                   "RTYPE":5,
                   "NO_DATA":0,
                   "COMPRESS":0,
                   "JPEGCOMPRESSION":1,
                   "ZLEVEL":1,
                   "PREDICTOR":1,
                   "TILED":False,
                   "BIGTIFF":2,
                   "EXTRA": '',
                   "OUTPUT":output/dir/test.tif})
```

I'm first getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpMAXfPw.py", line 11, in <module>
    attrs = layer.attributes()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'attributes'
```

Then, it seems that gdalogr:rasterize can't handle that `FIELD = n,`. Am I correct?

Could you, please, help me with this code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In `layer` you have only defined the path to a fine with a string. A simple Python string has no attribute 'attributes'. You need to actually create the layer first:

```
layer_path = "/home/klab-guest/Documents/shared-klab/PAM/Grid/grid_pam_1988.shp"
layer = iface.addVectorLayer(layer_path, "pam", "ogr")
attrs = layer.attributes()
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! It showed another error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpSDJStY.py", line 10, in <module>
    attrs = layer.attributes()
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'attributes'

Comment: I am no expert in Qt4. So I don't understand the intention of the code. But the message "object has no attribute 'attributes' " says it all. You are trying to call the method `attributes` on objects that don't have it. 
I think you mean  `fields()` or `get_Features()`: [link](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-viewing-vector-layer-attributes/)